# List index out of range when converting layers as a service definietion

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, service-definition

In ArcGIS Pro python window:

I'm adding certain layers into a list. From that list, I am converting the list in a service definition draft. I use this same script all the time, sometimes I'll get this "List out of range" and sometimes I don't so I don't why I get this error. I get this error when it's trying to run the create web layer SSD function. I've tried to remove the "[0]" part (don't know what this means), but I get a different error because of it.

```
    import arcpy


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('C:/naples/naples.aprx')
m = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]

lyrs=[]
lyrs.append(m.listLayers('Installation')[0])
lyrs.append(m.listLayers('Building_Area')[0])
lyrs.append(m.listLayers('Storage Tank')[0])
lyrs.append(m.listLayers('Structure Area')[0])


arcpy.mp.CreateWebLayerSDDraft(lyrs, 'C:/naples/service_definition/naples_installation.sddraft', 'naples_installation', 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES', 'FEATURE_ACCESS')
```

Comment: `aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]` the zero index is to fetch first listed map. Are you sure all your projects have maps? Which line of code give you the error?

Comment: The line of code where I get my error is at the "arcpy.mp.createWebLayerSDDraft" and it's because of my list, I believe. All my layers are in the same map. I've used this script several times, sometimes I'll get this error and sometimes I don't. I could just ignore the list part and use my "m" variable, but I don't want to convert all my layers in my map.

Comment: What is the length of lyrs after all of the appends? Is it always 4?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty difficult to provide an answer on "sometimes this errors, sometimes it doesn't" without seeing into your complete system/workflow.

The only advice I can offer is to add some debugging to your script which may highlight the error next time you attempt to run the workflow. As-is, your script expects very structured layer names. Any deviate from those names and it'll fail. The following code shows some more relaxed search patterns and debug techniques you could use.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('C:/naples/naples.aprx')
m = aprx.listMaps('Map')[0]

lyrs=[]

### Example 1 - wildcards
# Search for "Installation" by using a wild card after a few matching characters
lyrs.append(m.listLayers('Inst*')[0])
# Search for "Storage Tanks" by searching for "Storage" and anything after it via a wild card
lyrs.append(m.listLayers('Storage *')[0])

### Example 2 - basic reporting
searcher = "Installation"
l = m.listLayers(searcher )[0]
if l:
    lyrs.append(l)
else:
    print("Tried to add {}, but didn't find it".format(searcher))


### Example 3 - bit more robust search/reporting
# Make a list of your layer names you want to match
matchLayers = ["Installation", "Building_Area", "Storage Tank", "Structure Area"]
# Make a list of layer names found in the map
listLayerNames = [x.name for x in m.listLayers()]

# Loop through your list of layer names
for searchLayers in matchLayers:
    # If the name of your layer matches something in the map...
    if searchLayers in listLayerNames:
        # append that name to your lyrs variable 
        lyrs.append(m.listLayers(searchLayers)[0])
        # and remove it from the matchLayers list
        matchLayers.remove(searchLayers)

# And then at the end, print any layer not matched
print("The following layers were not found/matched:")
for p in matchLayers:
    print(" >  {}".format(p))

# And for debugging, print all the layers in the map so you can compare
print("These are the layers within the map:")
for p in listLayers:
    print(" >  {}".format(p))
```